# Calling a not CORS enabled API from node or react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors, microstrategy

I'm trying to call a MicroStrategy API from a react app, or a node backend, but i get a 401 unauthorized error back.

When running in postman or chrome (just pasting the url into the address bar), i get a status 200 response with an access token. Postman then generates the following nodejs code:

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://*/MicroStrategy/asp/TaskAdmin.aspx',
  qs: 
   { taskId: 'getSessionState',
     taskEnv: 'xml',
     taskContentType: 'xml',
     server: '*',
     project: '*',
     uid: '*',
     pwd: '*' },
  headers: 
   { 'postman-token': '9c7f6ca8-1ae4-b296-17cf-d850369cbad4',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

This code results in 401 error.

When trying the same from the client side (with react and axios), chrome throws the following error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

The problem is not the browser blocking CORS, it's the MicroStrategy server blocking the request, possibly because it has an 'Origin' header. Is there a way to make the exact same request in node as in postman?

Comment: I think it is the web-page blocking due to lack of CORS since you  are able to see it on chrome

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to let a user agent gain permission to access selected resources from a server on a different origin (domain) than the site currently in use.

you getting error because you are using different domains or port or protocol. If you want to resolve this issue you have to add response header in response.
try below code may be help

```
const app = express();

app.use("/api/*", function (request, response, next) {
response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
}
```

Comment: the resource is an iis server. i figured out that it works in chrome because of the windows authentication it does is the background. the response header is the following:

{"server":"Microsoft-IIS/8.5","www-authenticate":"Negotiate, NTLM","x-powered-by":"ASP.NET","date":"Tue, 20 Mar 2018 07:48:42 GMT","connection":"close","content-length":"0"}

probably i need to configure iis to allow unauthenticated requests.